# Recovery partition on Pixel 2 'does not exist'

Tags: recovery-mode, twrp, fastboot, google-pixel-2

I'm trying to get TWRP on my new Pixel 2 so I can get stock android with Magisk for root. My issue is according to Fastboot (just re-downloaded) there is no recovery. When I hit tab recovery does come up still. Here's my command and results:

```
gido5731@gido-desk:~/Downloads/platform-tools$ sudo ./fastboot flash recovery ../twrp-3.2.1-0-walleye.img
target reported max download size of 536870912 bytes
sending 'recovery' (32768 KB)...
OKAY [  0.098s]
writing 'recovery'...
FAILED (remote: No such partition.)
finished. total time: 0.098s
```

Comment: TWRP landing page says otherwise (says you can have a permanent recovery, just flashed in a different way); I've put the content in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoted from TWRP's [landing page](https://twrp.me/google/googlepixel2.html) for Pixel 2:

> **If you already have TWRP installed:** Download the latest zip and install the zip using TWRP.
>
> **If you do not already have TWRP installed:** Download both the img and the zip. You will need to have fastboot binaries and the correct drivers installed. Power off your device completely. Hold volume down and turn on the device. Your device should now be in the bootloader. Connect the device to your PC. Open a command window and run the following command from the proper location:
>
> `fastboot boot path/to/twrp.img`
>
> This will temporarily boot TWRP on your device. Use adb to push the zip onto your device:
>
> `adb push path/to/twrp.zip /`
>
> Go to install and browse to the zip and install the zip. The zip will install TWRP to both boot slots. Installing TWRP at this time will remove root if you are currently rooted.
>
> If you accidently flash TWRP to your device using fastboot instead of temporarily booting the image, you will need to download the latest factory image for your device and reflash the boot image.

Comment: That is true, Just a little further then I may go. Thanks for pointing this out! I may go and comment pushing it to `/` (anything for that matter) is 99% of times a bad idea, I'd recommend /sdcard personally.

Comment: Or `/tmp` which will be cleared upon reboot. Either way, just quoting that page faithfully, you know it well enough to tweak the process :)